# Wordpress does not show full style.css in theme editor

Tags: css, wordpress

#### What problem I faced:

Now I want to edit my theme's style.css file in wordpress admin,but it does not show full content,it just some summary info.But when I login my host by ssh,I could see full content in style.css.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58JVM.png)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Play';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(./font/ZNo-5SxCwH1CXgZ-n3bt2g.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215
}

body {
    font-family: "Play", "Microsoft Yahei", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.mr5 {
    margin-right: 5px
}

.mt0 {
    margin-top: 0
}

.mt5 {
    margin-top: 5px
}

.mt10 {
    margin-top: 10px
}

.mt15 {
    margin-top: 15px
}

.mt20 {
    margin-top: 20px
}

.mt25 {
    margin-top: 25px
}
```

```
wordpress version
5.2.7
```

Comment: You should probably not changing anything of your theme style sheet. It will be overwritten during theme update. use child theme or add simple css in customize

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your particular theme has stored all of its CSS in the 'Assets' folder of your theme. It is hard to tell from your screenshot alone.

If you want to modify your theme's CSS it is important that you [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). If you modify core theme files your changes will be overwritten the next time your theme updates. A child theme will keep all of your changes (actions/filters/css/javaScript etc.) save.

Comment: Thanks for ur help,I found the reason later, although it is pretty weird.My wordpress site url  mistakely, which is my wordpress's cdn url.Lately I just bind the my wordpress site url   correctly,then everything worked.